# C# saving excel file with specific filename using `[ ]` does not work

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to Save an Excel workbook with specific path and filename with file extension of `.xlsx`.

This is the full error, when I click the button to save:

> $exception    {"The file could not be accessed. Try one of the following:\n\n• Make sure the specified folder exists. \n• Make sure the folder that contains the file is not read-only.\n• Make sure the filename and folder path do not contain any of the following characters:  <  >  ?  [  ]  :  | or  *\n• Make sure the filename and folder path do not contain more than 218 characters."} System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

I see it says - `do not contain any of the following characters:  <  >  ?  [  ]  :  |`

**Code:**

```
//Path
string result = "C:\\Users\\LV98\\Desktop\\Test C#\\";

//Save Path
public string TheValue
{
    get { return $"{result}{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f8.filePath)} [{DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMyyyyHHmmss")}].xlsx"; }
}

//Button
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Excel Application
    excelApp = new Excel.Application();
    //Excel Workbooks
    workbooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
    //Excel Workbook
    target = workbooks.Add(f8.filePath);
    //Excel all sheets from Workbook
    Excel.Sheets sheets = target.Worksheets;
    //Get specific sheet name
    Excel.Worksheet workingSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(value);

    var newbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(1);

    workingSheet.Copy(newbook.Sheets[1]);

    newbook.SaveAs(TheValue); // ----------------------------------------------------- SAVE VALUE HERE
    newbook.Close();

    target.Close();
    excelApp.Quit();
    killExcel();

    this.Close()    
}
```

**Details:**

I clearly Have `[]` in my Save As file path.

But I am able to create a file manually, and name it using `[]` without a problem..

[image]

This is the output of `TheValue`:

[image]

**Concern:**

Why is this not letting me use `[]`?

Comment: `\ / : * ? " < > |` Those are impossible characters.

Comment: @TheGridLock and OP filename doesn't contain any of them. OP is asking about `[ ]`

Comment: i think he to save a file and the path exceeds 255 characters! so he receive this error.

Comment: @TheGridLock No, the path is posted and only has 56.

Comment: Don't make me guess. only he knows what is really going on!

Comment: I believe the com api has more restrictions than the direct api to create files. I can create a file using streamwriter and [ ] in the name.

Comment: Another thing you can try is give a regular name while using com wrapper. Than move the file with [ using System.IO.File.Move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general Excel restriction and not related to COM specifically, you'll get exactly the same message if you try to try to save a file from within Excel that contains square brackets in the name. I imagine the reason is that in Excel you can reference another workbook file in a formula using something like this:

```
='E:\Temp\[Test.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

I don't believe there's any way to escape the bracket characters so including those will make it impossible to reference it from another workbook. I'd recommend rather than try to work around it you stick with parentheses which are allowed, but if someone is insisting that the files are named that way you could just do something like the following:

```
public string TheValue
{
   get { return $"{result}{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f8.filePath)} ({DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMyyyyHHmmss")}).xlsx"; }
}
File.Move(TheValue, TheValue.Replace("(","[").Replace(")","]"));
```

That's assuming there's no possibility the filename will already contain parentheses, if it can you could just initially save it to a unique filename in Excel and then use your existing `TheValue` as the final target for the `File.Move`.